# LINQ method How to SelectMany with additional column from Parent class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class :

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

With `Parent` object, here's how I get all `Childs` value.

```
Parent obj = GetParent();
PrintExcel(obj.SelectMany(sm => sm.Childs);
```

But I also want to include `ParentName` value in the select command, how to achieve this?

With SQL query, I can do this

```
SELECT
    p.ParentName,
    c.ChildName
FROM
    Parent p
    INNER JOIN Child c ON
        p.ParentID = c.ParentID
```

Comment: Change the signature of `PrintExcel` to take it: `PrintExcel(obj.ParentName, obj.SelectMany(sm => sm.Childs))`

Comment: I'd like to do this in one linq select and PrintExcel method cannot be modified.

Comment: if it can't be modified you have to modify class `Child` to include a reference to it's parent. Currently the method `PrintExcel` takes an `IEnumerable<Child>` which has no knowledge of the `Parent`.

Comment: **Edit** Your sql query selects not only child records. So either extend `Child` with a new property `Parent Parent`(or at least `string ParentName`) or modify the method `PrintExcel` with a new parameter `string parentName` which seems to be the easiest and most logical approach. You could select both, but it wouldn't help you since you can't pass the anonymous type to the method: `obj.SelectMany(sm => new{ ParentName = obj.ParentName ,sm.Childs })`

Comment: With `Parent` **object**? `SelectMany` works on sequences, not single objects.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your LINQ example is flawed. Assuming you have a **sequence** of `Parent` (i.e. `IEnumerable<Parent>` or `IQueryable<Parent>`) called `parents`, you can access the parent inside the `SelectMany` at least in a two ways:

(A) Use `Select` inside the `SelectMany`:

```
parents.SelectMany(p => p.Childs.Select(c => new { p.ParentName, c.ChildName }))
```

(B) Use the `SelectMany` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you pass result selector:

```
parents.SelectMany(p => p.Childs, (p, c) => new { p.ParentName, c.ChildName })
```

And of course you can simply use the **query syntax** and let the compiler determine the correct method for you:

```
(from p in parents from c in p.Childs select new { p.ParentName, c.ChildName })
```